# Save and open a TimerTime in the Preferences

Tags: java, android

I'm currently working on a small Android game. In the options menu you can select the time you wish to play, either 15, 30 or 45 seconds. I have a countdown timer that loads these values. Now on my onPause, I want to save the current time and then onResume proceed from that time.

```
protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        final SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
        int cTime = Integer.valueOf(sharedPrefs.getString("playTimePref", null));
        TimerTime = cTime;
        timer = new CountDownTimer(TimerTime, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                mTextField.setText("Seconds Remaining: " + millisUntilFinished/ 1000);
                TimerTime = (int) millisUntilFinished;
            }

protected void onPause() {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("playTimePref", "TimerTime");
        timer.cancel();
    }
```

I thought this would work. If I'm correct I save the current TimerTime in the playTimePref string at onPause, and open that on onResume. But everytime I recall the app, the time resets to its original time. Hope someone can help.

Comment: you need to commit the editor after put the string in it

Comment: Hi mohammed. Thanks for the comment. I have that in the original project, just forgot to copy it here. I tried both .apply and .commit but both don't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but is `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext())` the same as `getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE)`? How about using only one expression on both methods?

Answer (score 0):

this method

```
 final SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
```

will create the shared preference with your package name (com.xxx.xxx) and will be accessible by all activities you have.

but this method

```
getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE)
```

will create shared Preference with your activity name (MainActivity) and it will be accessible only with your activity because your assign  private mode for it , so as you can see you try to save your data in sharedPref and try to access the values from another one , that's why it return null for you

another comment on your code , you can use save time of casting string to int by using strong type mehod

```
Editor.putInt("Key" , timenumber);
```

hope it help you